# How do I enable kvm virtualization using command line in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am a newbee to Android Mobile Development. 
I have installed Android Studio on my Linux Machine and tried running the Hello World App but the emulator(android virtual device) doesn't run. I added kvm virtualisation but can't see the emulator tab. Therefore, I tried using command line but am not able to go through it. I saw many forums but there was no clear direction. 
It will be great if you could provide a clear direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Worked for ubuntu 20.04, I used this command because it seems `ibvirt-bin` is removed.
`sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils`

Answer (score 3):

**Install the KVM**

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

You may ignore the Postfix Configuration prompt by selecting "*No Configuration*".

**Add your local user account to the group kvm and libvirtd.**

```
sudo adduser your_user_name kvm
sudo adduser your_user_name libvirtd
```

In Ubuntu 16.10, the group has been renamed to libvirt instead of libvirtd.

After the installation, you need to relogin so that your user account becomes an effective member of kvm and libvirtd user groups. The members of this group can run virtual machines.

**Verify installation in Terminal:**

```
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

If you see: *Id Name*  *State* list.

**Add the emulator command line options.**

In Android Studio, go to *Run* > *Edit Configurations*.
To set as global default for all projects, select "Android Application" under "Defaults".
Go to the emulator tab, check "*Additional command line options*" and add:

```
-qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

You can check all prerequisite and installation step on below link also:

https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/wiki/1.-Setting-Up-Android-Studio-on-Ubuntu#install-intels-kvm-for-better-avd-performance

Comment: I followed it but there is no emulator tab displayed.
I am able to do all the steps above it but not the last one. that's the issue.

Comment: *Additional command line options* was removed after android studio 1.4.1 
:(